# Исходники игры Mario!

Tags: c++

Добрый день уважаемые гуру!Не сочтите мой вопрос глупым,я начинающий и действительно не могу разобраться:(

В общем скачал исходники игры **Mario:**.Никак не могу запустить саму игру.

***Вот папка с проектом:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Вот папка с экзешником:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открывал проект в visual studio,чтобы запустить его,никак не получается,кучу ошибок выдает,видимо из-за версий(у меня 2019,в исходниках 2010)

Также напрямую запускал экзешник,выдает следующую **ошибку:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался решить эту проблему,скачал необходимый пакет от microsoft,все равно не работает!

Помогите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: Попробуйте скачать Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2010-2019 годов. Это где-то 4-5 версий. Возможно поможет.

Comment: Попробуйте открывать не существующий `Mario.sln`, а сделать новый проект в своей версии VS и туда включить исходники

Comment: Суффикс `D` в названии библиотеки показывает, этот бинарик требует *отладочный* вариант  Visual C++ Redistributable 2010, который устанавливается только вместе с инструментами Visual C++ 2010. Так что вам надо поставить Visual Studio 2010. Ну либо пересобрать с использованием Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @user7860670 Простите,можете поподробнее рассказать,как пересобрать ?